# If CHttpConnection::OpenRequest returns NULL how do I find out why

Tags: c++, mfc, httpwebrequest

c++
mfc

if CHttpConnection::OpenRequest  returns a null what can I use to get the internet error. 
The mfc artical doesn't say what a bad responce looks like.  I just said it returns a handle to a CHttpFile.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you see what is the error code returned by GetLastError() ? Get the error code and perform a error lookup (Tools->Error Lookup) to get the description about the code. Normally you will get the exact reason for the failure using this.